# How to reduce a $(\log_2n)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics

I am given 5 algorithms and the steps they took like $O(n^2)$, $o(n^2)$, $Ω(n^2)$, $Ω(n)$

I am asked to associate certain equations with the above and one of these is:

$$(\log_2 n)^2+75$$

And

$$7n!$$

Any ideas how this would be solved? Specifically for the first one as I cannot seem to find a log rule that may apply. My only option I see is that it definitely grows slower than $n^2$ and larger than $Ω(\log n)$. Is this correct?

Comment: You are right about the first one. For the second one, take a look at Stirling's formula.